# Take second element of NavigatableList

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is html:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1 EUR</td><td>4,2989</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 USD</td><td>3,7575</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 CHF</td><td>3,8245</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 GBP</td><td>4,7907</td></tr>
<tr><td>100 JPY</td><td>3,4727</td></tr>
</table>
```

and I want to print the numbers like `4,2989`, `3,7575` etc.

I have tried many methods but nothin works. For instance:

```
for c in soup.children:
    print(c.contents[1])
```

error

```
for c in soup.children:
    print(c.find("td")[1])
```

error

```
for c in soup.children:
    for cc in c.children:
        print(cc)
```

error

```
for c in soup.children:
    print(c.next_sibling)
```

error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<table>
<tr><td>1 EUR</td><td>4,2989</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 USD</td><td>3,7575</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 CHF</td><td>3,8245</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 GBP</td><td>4,7907</td></tr>
<tr><td>100 JPY</td><td>3,4727</td></tr>
</table>""")
```

`soup.children` returns only one tag, the body one, so it won't work.

A way to do it is to use the `find_all` method as follow:

```
for x in soup.find_all('tr'): # Iterate over tr tags
    print(x.find_all('td')[1].text) # find the second td tag and get its text

# Ouptput: 4,2989 3,7575 3,8245 4,7907 3,4727
```

Keep in mind those numbers are string, you will need to convert them befor eusnig them as float

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i think why you are getting an error is because the `.children` will also contain line separators such as '\n' which will be treated as `bs4.element.NavigableString.`If you treat it as a tag you'll most proabably get an`AttributeError:`

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<table>
<tr><td>1 EUR</td><td>4,2989</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 USD</td><td>3,7575</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 CHF</td><td>3,8245</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 GBP</td><td>4,7907</td></tr>
<tr><td>100 JPY</td><td>3,4727</td></tr>
</table>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table')
for child in table.children:
    print(repr(child))
```

Output

```
'\n'
<tr><td>1 EUR</td><td>4,2989</td></tr>
'\n'
<tr><td>1 USD</td><td>3,7575</td></tr>
'\n'
<tr><td>1 CHF</td><td>3,8245</td></tr>
'\n'
<tr><td>1 GBP</td><td>4,7907</td></tr>
'\n'
<tr><td>100 JPY</td><td>3,4727</td></tr>
'\n'
```

One solution would be to get process only those that are not NavigableString.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<table>
<tr><td>1 EUR</td><td>4,2989</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 USD</td><td>3,7575</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 CHF</td><td>3,8245</td></tr>
<tr><td>1 GBP</td><td>4,7907</td></tr>
<tr><td>100 JPY</td><td>3,4727</td></tr>
</table>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table')
for child in table.children:
    if type(child) is not bs4.element.NavigableString:
        print(child.findAll('td')[1].text)
```

Output:

```
4,2989
3,7575
3,8245
4,7907
3,4727
```